# .cshtml intellisense for console application

Tags: html, razor, console-application, intellisense

I am trying to utilize cshtml in console application(Azure Webjob) for sending emails.

I tried following instructions [here](https://antaris.github.io/RazorEngine/IntellisenseAndResharper.html) but as soon as I type `@using RazorEngine` it gives me an error `namespace not found`. How can I get intellisense support with RazorEngine nuget package installed?

**EDIT:** Following this [RazorEngine configuration link](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine#configuring-razor-using-appconfig-or-webconfig) I created a `Views Folder` in root of console application. Created a new `App.Config` under `Views folder` with the following code in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
  </configSections>
  <razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="my.namespace" />
    </namespaces>
  </razor>
</configuration>
```

Still intellisense doesn't work.